# TypeError when trying to print contents of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, iteration, typeerror

I try to convert an array from a list to array: In fact I have slipt traces in 9 groups tempTracesHW [hw]  hw=[0,9]then I want to display just one element from each temTracesHW, so I convert tempTracesHW[i] into a table like this:

```
tempTraces = np.load(r'E:\\blockData\\Concatenated_Traces.npy')

print (tempTraces.shape)     
tempSbox = [inv_sbox[tempCText[i][0] ^ tempKey[i][0]] for i in range(len(tempCText))] 
tempHW   = [hw[s] for s in tempSbox]

tempTracesHW = [[] for _ in range(9)]
print tempTracesHW
        # Fill them up
for i in range(len(tempTraces)):
    HW = tempHW[i]
    tempTracesHW[HW].append(tempTraces[i])

# Switch to numpy arrays        
tempTracesHW = [np.array(tempTracesHW[HW]) for HW in range(9)]
print(tempTracesHW)

for i in range(HW):
    print('hw=',i)
    print(len(tempTracesHW[i]))
    print(tempTracesHW[i])
    Tab= np.asarray(tempTracesHW[i])
    print(Tab.shape)
    for k in len(Tab):
        print(Tab[k])
```

But it gives me this error:

```
    for k in len(Tab):

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You need to create an iterable from the int returned by `len`: `for k in range(len(Tab))`, prolly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `enumerate` if you want to have the option to iterate over the indices or the actual values.

```
for i, k in enumerate(Tab):
    print(Tab[i]) # print(k)
```

You cannot iterate over `len(Tab)` because it is a scalar, not an iterable.

---

`Tab` is a numpy array, and these have gorgeous looking `__repr__` implementations. Why not just `print(Tab)`?

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
for k in Tab:
   print k
```

the len(Tab) give the length of Tab.

Comment: The OP wants to iterate _index_-wise, not element wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.asarray([1,2,3])
a_list = list(ar)
```

For your code:

```
for k in list(Tab):
```